# How do I get the restricted drivers update on xubuntu, does not show-up in update manager?

Tags: software-installation

How do I get the restricted drivers update on xubuntu, does not show-up in update manager? The restricted driver icon is not available on the launch bar on top.

Comment: Do they appear in a hardware menu in your system settings dialogue as they do in Unity?

Answer (score 2):

The application that you have mentioned is called `jockey` and is usually accessed via its gtk GUI just run `jockey-gtk`

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/jockey-gtk

Answer (score 1):

In newer Ubuntu versions (I don't know since when exactly, but my 12.10 is like this) the jockey application has been replaced by another tab in the software sources window. To get there directly, run `software-properties-gtk` and select the tab to the very right.